# What is the correct place to put delegate in MVVM

Tags: objective-c

If we say that View and View Controller can be considered as View in MVVM, then shall we use Delegates in ModelView (which is for business logic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if it's a view's delegate - put it in the **View Model**. If it's model-level delegate not related to the UI, implement it in the **Model**.

Comment: Thanks, it was quite simple to understand.

Comment: If the delegate is related to networking, which is not directly related to UI will it be still in the model.

Comment: @SaurabhSaini, yes. And you may use notifications or create a custom delegate to update your UI when you receive and parse network data. That delegate must be implemented in View Model.

Answer (score 1):

your question is pretty unclear, but I can still provide an outline / guideline for you.

Typically as your apps evolve with more complexity, you'll need view models for each of your views that can be customized and described by data. You want your view controllers to be clean and very readable, and as a result, you should only use view controllers as containers for your custom views. Your custom views can have a view model property with a `didSet` that allows it to modify and configure the view. For example, when I dequeue a cell from a tableView, I would give the `(cell as? MyCustomCellClass)?.viewModel = aViewModel` to make it extremely readable. You use delegates to handle business logic by setting delegates appropriately to communicate between a subview and a view, or from a tableViewCell to whatever controller is managing and extending the `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDataSource`. So all in all, your MVVM architecture will rely on custom View Models that you can use to configure your custom views, while you have controller objects managing business logic and handling the flow of data between things at a lower level with things at the higher level. If you have a specific example you'd like help with, please post some code. Hope this helped!